# React-Router-Dom 6+ throwing Attempted import error: 'withRouter' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

When I try to run with 'react-router-dom@6.0.0-beta.0' I get

> Attempted import error: 'withRouter' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

```
import {Route, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

What is the replacement?

**Update**

These links suggest that a global object should be used is there a better way?

[Link 1](https://morioh.com/p/995f1244f33b)
[Link 2](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7156)

Comment: import { withRouter } from "react-router"

Answer (score 0):

This version doesn't support 'withRouter',instead, you can use some other properties such as
useLocation,
useNavigate,
useParams

,then by using these are you can define 'withRouter ',also avoid to change version of react-router-dom. Use this code for solve the problem

```
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}
```